Camera closes the Android 14 Ionic angular cordova application
According to the requirements, I updated my Ionic angular application to Android 14 (API level 34) to be submitted to Google Play...
But now I have a problem, on devices with Android 14 version,  this.camera.getPicture() stops the app.
Error I find in adb logcat:
PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Camera.takePicture blocked the main 
thread for 43ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

I use:
ionic 7
Angular 17

"cordova-plugin-camera": "^7.0.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^6.8.0"

How to resolve this problem?
On devices with Android13 camera works as expected..

Do you Still use Cordova or also implemented Capacitor?
Which Phone is it exactly? Had the problem only with some Xiaomi and some Huawei but not all of them

So what does the xcode console log say? it must show something. -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@FloSojer, how did you solve it?
I am using just Cordova. it happens on android studio emulator and real samsung s22 device

Use the version "cordova-plugin-camera": "8.0.0"
